# Lost driving license In EU. Other ID methods?

Tags: uk, schengen, eu, identity-cards

I foolishly left my wallet in Utrecht while interrailing and lost my UK driving license among other things. I've sorted most of the ramifications of the loss but I need another ID to prove I'm over 18 in countries in the EU.

Are there any options other than my passport? Could I obtain some identity card?

Comment: What IDs do you have? Obviously what IDs are accepted is dependent on country, although your passport will usually work everywhere. If you don't like taking your passport out with you, you could apply for a new licence and get someone to post it out to you?

Comment: I would not literally "post" but send it through one of the courier services that tracks every step and delivers fast.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there's anything you can get which would be both as widely accepted as a driving license and easier to obtain than one.

Comment: The easiest option might be your passport - obviously it's not ideal carrying it around, but it should be accepted everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sorry about your misfortune, but use your passport.

Lot of countries have an ID card, but you're British and you live in Britian, so you can't get one.

There are alternative forms of ID for proving your age in the UK, like the "Proof of Age Standards Scheme", but I doubt those have any traction outside of the UK. Maybe you could use your shotgun certificate if you have one. I imagine some places are strict about these things, and some will take anything official looking with a name, photo and date of birth.

The thing about all these IDs though (including an ID card), is that it would take just as much or more time and hassle to get them as to replace your driving licence. There is no "emergency form of ID" except in the case where you actually do lose your passport.

Comment: And that "emergency form of ID" is a travel permission obtained from one's country's embassy or consulate, and only useful for returning to one's home country. It's likely to be time-limited, too.